# free(): invalid next size (fast) in C

Tags: c, free

Been trying to figure out this bug for the last couple of days in my program. It works fine on my test cases if I increase the size of my `#defined LINE_SIZE`, but that would only be a temporary fix to my problem.

In this part of the code, I read every line in a file, and increment a spot in memory for each specific character I find. ascii points to a `malloc`'d area of 256 ints.

```
void readFile(FILE *fp, int *ascii) {
   char *line;
   char *temp;

   while (!feof(fp)) {
      line = readLine(fp);
      if (line == NULL)
         break;
      temp = line;
      while (*temp  != '\0') {
         (*(ascii + *temp))++;
         temp++;
      }
      free(line);          <-------------- BREAKS HERE
   }
   fclose(fp);
}

char* readLine(FILE *fp) {
   char *rtn = NULL;
   int last = -1;
   int size = LINE_SIZE;             <------ LINE_SIZE = 8

   do {
      rtn = (char*)realloc(rtn,size);
      if (!rtn) {
         printf("Realloc failed\n");
         exit(1);
      }
      fgets(rtn + last + 1, size, fp);
      if (feof(fp))
         break;
      last = strlen(rtn) - 1;
      size += size;
      if (rtn[last] == '\n')
         break;
   } while (rtn[last] != '\0');
   return rtn;
}
```

I'm trying to have my code read its own .c file, and it breaks on line 58 in a 250 line file: `void makeList(int *ascii, LinkNode *list) {`

In gdb, printing `line` right before I free it gives me:

```
(gdb) print line
$1 = 0x9849578 "void makeList(int *ascii, LinkNode *list) {\n"
```

Which is exactly what I would expect it to print. The code crashes right after, when it tries to free this line that I no longer need.

Comment: Why in the world are you reading line-by-line? Just read a big chunk of data (say, 4MB) via `fread` into a buffer allocated when you open the file; do your histogram-thingy and then read the next chunk. When your reach EOF, just close the file and deallocate the buffer. If you really want to try something hardcore-ish, use `mmap`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the correct buffer size to `fgets()`. Even though you're allocating that many bytes, you are passing in an offset into your buffer and you need to account for that:

```
fgets(rtn + last + 1, size - last - 1, fp);
```

Comment: Oh. Hurr durr me :/. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

ascii points to an area of 256*4=1024 bytes, and you're copying the lines you read into it; so unless your lines are (on average) about 20 characters long, you're going to run off the end of that buffer before you get to line 58.  May not be causing free to fail, but it can't be helping.